# How do I view my score for tag?

Tags: discussion, support

I recently earned the [create tag synonyms](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) privilege, and I want to view my score for tag.

I tried to suggest a tag synonyms, but it shows "**tag synonym requires 5 score**".  where can I check my score for tag ?

> [image]

Comment: To be honest, I don't think these 2 should be synonyms. Nodeblock is much narrower and specialised term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's shown on https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/12418/bala?tab=tags&sort=votes&page=1 and following pages; the number to the left of the tag is your score for the tag.

> [image: screenshot]

Keep in mind that the tag synonym needs to be voted by 4 users, to get approved. The required score is for the tag for which you are suggesting the synonym, not the tag being suggested as synonym.

I also agree with Mołot about the tag synonym not being correct: [blocks](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blocks) is rather broader than the tag for which you are trying to suggest the synonym.

Comment: Obligatory +1 for freehand circles. We don't get enough of those around here